# Delete char* for byte conversion

Tags: c++, c

I tried to read a binary file using different length byte every time I read the file. After I got the value, I try to convert the bytes to `char*`.

I created a simple code as follows:

```
//This code is compiled in Visual Studio 2010
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

BYTE *s;
s = new BYTE[3]; // I read 2 bytes from the file, I add +1 to reserve NULL
s[0]= 'a'; s[1]='b';s[2]=NULL;  //just an example I get 2 bytes from file

char* b;
b = new char(sizeof(s));
strcpy(b,(char*)s);
s[0]='x';
cout << s <<"--"<< b<< "--"<< endl;
delete[] s;
delete[]  b;
cin.get();
return 0;`
```

However, the code generates error "Heap Corruption Detected". When I removed the line, `delete[] b;` the program runs well. But I am not sure the next time if the problem may arise. Will somebody explain about it, please? Will it cause memory leak if I remove `delete[] b;`?  Any suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: I'm sorry. It is a typo, it should be 's'.

Comment: You can always edit your own post by clicking on the "edit" link button below it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While David Saxon has explained the immediate reason for your error, your code could be significantly improved by the use of the C++ standard library:

```
//This code is compiled in Visual Studio 2010
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

//s will be automatically destroyed when control leaves its scope
//so there is no need for the `delete[]` later on, and there
//will be no memory leaks if the construction of `b` fails.
std::vector<BYTE> s(3);// I read 2 bytes from the file, I add +1 to reserve NULL
s[0]= 'a'; s[1]='b';s[2]=NULL;  //just an example I get 2 bytes from file
//`sizeof s` is wrong, as it gives the size of the `s` object, rather than
//the size of the allocated array.
//Here I instead just make `b` as a copy of `s`.
std::vector<BYTE> b(s);
s[0]='x';
cout << s.data() <<"--"<< b.data() << "--"<< endl;
//There is no need for `delete[] s` and `delete[] b` as `s` and `b`
//have automatic storage duration and so will automatically be destroyed.
cin.get();
return 0;`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for improving my code. I can see clearer now and I learn something new here.

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
b = new char(sizeof(s));
```

Should be:

```
b = new char[sizeof(s)];
```

Otherwise you are not creating an array, you are just just creating a pointer to a char that has the character code of sizeof(a).

And therefore delete[] b is causing it to crash because you are trying to delete an array where there is no array.

Also another problem, sizeof(s) is not going to give you what you want. s is a dynamically allocated array so calling sizeof(s) is **not** going to give you the sum of the sizes of chars in s. sizeof(s) will return the size of the pointer to s.